# clickable response in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, hyperlink, dialogflow-es

I am creating a simple chatbot which contains some common college related questions and their responses. In one of the responses, I need to add a link. Lets say to navigate to the college website. I am using node.js for fulfillment and I have no idea how to implement the same.
The response is to be driven from the database.[image: I tried adding the anchor tag in the response as shown in the image]

Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: You have to give a link directly as a string or have to bind with a button, card payload.

Comment: I am extracting a response from the database. Based on few responses, I need to convert them into a link. Do i need to have a html file for that, or is it possible inside index.js itself?

Comment: you can send it directly as text message if it will be link then it will shown as hyperlink

Comment: No it does not. I am getting the response as a normal text.